# Set Designer ToolBox proterties for custom controls

Tags: c#, icons, controls, designer

I've made a few custom controls to use in my projects, but i can't figure out how to set custom icons or descriptions like the pre-made visual studio controls have when you hover over them in the toolbox.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB7DN.png]

So far i've tried using this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of my Control
/// </summary>
```

And adding this attribute to my control class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description("Description of my Control")]
```

But i just cant figure it out, does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the attribute [System.ComponentModel.Description("Description of my Control")] is exactly what you need. But be sure to install the control in the toolbox, otherwise you wont be able to see the custom description. You could do this by adding a new tab in the toolbox, and choosing the item you want, like [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/d3065c5e-552e-4aa1-97e3-769441c467b6/).